# How to differentiate between multiple PKPaymentPasses in Apple Wallet?

Tags: ios, swift, applepay, apple-wallet

We have implemented a feature in our iOS app that allows users to link their bank cards and generate PKPaymentPasses, which can be added to the Apple Wallet. However, we are facing an issue when users link multiple cards from different banks. It becomes difficult for them to distinguish between the cards, except by remembering the last 4 digits.

We would like to provide a better user experience by allowing customization of the PKPaymentPasses we add to the Apple Wallet. Is there any way we can achieve this? We want to enable users to easily identify and differentiate between the multiple passes they have added.

We appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to customize the PKPaymentPasses to enhance the user experience. Thank you in advance for your help!